# How to enable debug logging in Apache CXF before encrypting

Tags: java, logging, cxf, ws-security

I already have enabled debug logs for my WS-Client like this

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
loggingInInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
LoggingOutInterceptor loggingOutInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
loggingOutInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);
client.getInInterceptors().add(loggingInInterceptor);
```

Unfortunately this produces Output like this:

```
[...]
<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="_fac28258-8b72-4e26-8936-f8ec39d36941">
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-c2e3310c-c15c-44f9-b458-d2f84bbad79f" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
        [...]
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</soap:Body>
```

Which is not really helpful if I need to clarify the transmitted business data.

Is there a way to get the outgoing SOAP envelop before encryption and respective the incoming SOAP envelop after decryption?

Comment: Thanks for client-side logging snippet, I could not find it in the CXF documentation.

Comment: Did you find an aswer by anychance?

Comment: Yes. Please see my own answer I just added to this thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to produce my desired logging by implementing my own LogginInterceptor like this:

```
public class CleartextLogger extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    private static final String LOG_SETUP = CleartextLogger.class.getName() + ".log-setup";
    private Logger logger;

    public CleartextLogger(Logger logger) {
        super(Phase.POST_PROTOCOL);
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        try {
            boolean logged = message.containsKey(LOG_SETUP);
            if (!logged) {
                message.put(LOG_SETUP, Boolean.TRUE);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                SOAPMessage smsg = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
                if(smsg != null)  {
                    smsg.writeTo(bout);
                    log(bout.toString());
                } else {
                    logger.warn("Es gab keinen verschlüsselten Inhalt zu loggen");
                }
            }
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void log(String xml) {
        StringReader in = new StringReader(xml);
        StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
        XMLStreamWriter xwriter = StaxUtils.createXMLStreamWriter(swriter);
        xwriter = new PrettyPrintXMLStreamWriter(xwriter, 2);
        try {
            StaxUtils.copy(new StreamSource(in), xwriter);
        } catch (XMLStreamException xse) {
            //ignore
        } finally {
            try {
                xwriter.flush();
                xwriter.close();
            } catch (XMLStreamException xse2) {
                //ignore
            }
            in.close();
        }

        String result = swriter.toString();
        logger.debug(result);
    }
}
```

And add this Interceptor for outgoing/incoming logs in the interceptor chains:

```
CleartextLogger clearOutputLogger = new CleartextLogger(logger);
CleartextLogger clearInputLogger = new CleartextLogger(logger);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(clearOutputLogger);
client.getInInterceptors().add(clearInputLogger);
```

The `logger` object is an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.

This logger logs before encryption and after decryption.

Comment: This works for before encryption, but not if we want to log the step after signature. Do you know how to do after signature and before encryption ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Isn't the signature build based on the encrypted content?

Answer (score 2):

Encryption happens in PRE_PROTOCOL phase for output chain. You have to set the logging interceptor to a phase before this one if you want to log clear messages.
You can pass the phase in the interceptor constructor.
CXF phase doc : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: If I modify my LoggingOutInterceptor like this `new LoggingOutInterceptor(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL)` the only output for my outgoing message is this: `ID: 1
Address: https://[...]
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["http://tempuri.org/IServiceCustomer/InsertCustomer"]}`